# Return documents contains only one value in field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two documents:

```
POST /test/_doc/1
{
    "id": 1
    "tags": [1, 2, 3]
}

POST /test/_doc/2
{
    "id": 2
    "tags": [2]
}
```

If I search documents with tags = 2, both documents returns:

```
POST /test/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "tags": 2
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I search documents that contains only the tags = 2 value, not others? In this case I need return only the second document.

Comment: might be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54315343/elasticsearch-find-exact-match-in-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to use a script query and specify the doc values' [`size()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/7.0.0/org/elasticsearch/index/fielddata/ScriptDocValues.html):

```json
POST /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "tags": 2
          }
        },
        {
          "script": {
            "script": "doc['tags'].size() == 1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```